# Extract some data with python from a json content

Tags: python, json, api

Hello guys and girls,

I have the following code :

```
import json
import pprint

with open('77.json', 'r') as file:
data = json.load(file)

somedata = data.get('"name":')
printer = pprint.PrettyPrinter()

print('somedata')
```

And the code in json file it's like this :

[
    {
        "id": "0f78f3f6-0efe-49bc-9283-7daf23c142f0",
        "name": "Utilizing Network Devices For DHCP",
        "slug": "utilizing-network-devices-for-dhcp",
        "duration_in_seconds": 473,
        "status": "ready",
        "metadata": {
            "company": "xxx"
        },
        "instructor_id": "e72b1785-711e-42b4-b795-f3523fe3a7d8",
        "created": "2020-04-15T01:18:51Z",
        "modified": "2020-04-30T18:34:46.111771Z",
        "s3_video_url": "http//:blabla4",
        "excel_id": "e1ZTXDBr"
    },
    {

The problem is that i get an error with my code :

```
 python test.py
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
somedata = data.get('"name":')
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'
```

And i want to extract everything from "name":

Here is how it looks the json content:
https://video.rmotr.com/api/v1/videos?page_size=none&ids=5114e573,a2ad2115,e2695b5e,f0b3f815,27f349a9,dd1e51f4,1f9aba83,d09dae17,2d20f05a,6a90013d,628d73da,512eb96f,41677d9e,0a816753,0fbac17e,198911c1,0f78f3f6,6d300633,1a8072ca,d0853666,a6215f7a,8247903e,cd0f87a3,0afe6c8e,c65927d7,b26d523e,c1c45d2d,82ccc733,cf6b2949,220696da,2d38eb42,5fc5b96f,f84ff818,8037600d,33eaa6ee,9d319c7a,2889e3e0,d511906c,d13c6b4d,ac8e0c0c,c0ddcf1f,5402d2bc,9355a08c,438db984,abe48951,f4bafb9e,54418fb3,bfa32e61,264be932,549340c7,fe1ebace,c4eed340,1f1747dc,bae9ee4b,1f5a8478,11bec186,eb57362d,68ff2689,6f60b2f7,3d154afd,40706ef8,5b52955e,4607b4e6,c32fa88f,46290537,b8755d8e,cd61a627,0cfc4e27,88804d99,d53474ea&parent_type=course&parent_id=9581c375-e70d-4e54-a425-51a05c02157a

And i want to extract all the info from each line where it start with "name":

It should look like this :

```
  Introducing Northbound & Southbound APIs
  SDN’s Relationship To Management, Control & Data Planes
```

So on and so forth.

Sorry, but i forgot to mention that i am a beginer.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The exception ```AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'``` means that data is a `list`, and `list` doesn't have the `get` attribute.

Comment: What about data[“name”]?

Answer (score 1):

Your json file contains an array of objects. So when you load it, you're getting a list of dicts. To get the name field, you would need to look at the individual entries of the list:

```
for entry in data:
    somedata = entry.get('name')
```